# What format does fget(); return in PHP? (Evaluating String)

Tags: php, string, file

I'm trying to execute an IF Statement that chooses which image is displayed depending on what what string it reads from the file, either the string "ROTTEN" or the string "FRESH". However, even if the file has "ROTTEN" in it, it always goes to the else portion no matter what. Am I evaluating the IF statement correctly? Its reading the correct line, I know that for sure.

```
if(strcasecmp(fgets($myfile), 'ROTTEN') == 0){
    echo "<img src='https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif' alt='Rotten' />";
}else{
    echo "<img src='https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif' alt='Fresh' />";
};
```

Comment: `'fgets($myfile)'` - variables are not evaluated in single quotes and no idea why you even used those for the function. Just remove them `if(strcasecmp(fgets($myfile)`. Edit: this as per your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42163578/1

Comment: this doesn't work either `if(fgets($myfile) == "ROTTEN")`

Comment: we also don't know what `$myfile` is and where it's assigned as well as its actual content. In any case; you've been given an answer below, ask them.

Comment: echo/var_dump `fgets($myfile)`, what do you get?

Comment: Btw, you went and stealth edited your question without marking it as an edit and the person below stands to get downvoted because of it. Edit: they deleted their first answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, appears to me I added edit changelog?

Comment: @aynber i either get ROTTEN or FRESH returned

Comment: not everyone knows about changelogs; keep that in mind for visitors who don't know of it. That should have been mentioned in the question also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I apologize then, didn't realize using the form to say why I edited wasn't enough for people to know why I edited.

Comment: When someone else visits the question (future visitors), they see the posted code right away, not changelogs and again; they may not know about them, remember that. I just want answerers to be spared of potential downvotes. Some actually do think like this: *"There's no quotes around it, so why the answer?"* ;-) Just trying to be a good Samaritan here. Edit: same thing goes for (my) comments. @DakotaWagner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strpos() function:

```
if(strpos(fgets($myfile), 'ROTTEN') !== false){
    echo "<img src='https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif' alt='Rotten' />";
}else{
    echo "<img src='https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif' alt='Fresh' />";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

fgets return the a line as a string, with the length if you defined or 1kB. this also include the EOL, so you compare will not be true. You may use the length parameter or strpos or substr to check it.

Comment: Or trim it. That will remove all whitespace on either side.